# How to remove "" from the database values

Tags: php

I am fetching data through cURL, and storing it in array so while exploding and printing the values are coming like "iPhone", so how to remove "", so that i will get output like: iPhone

Comment: Try, str_replace('"', '', $value);

Comment: May strings contain quotes sub-strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove only surrounding characters:

```
trim($value, '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code :

```
 str_replace('"',"",$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `str_replace('"', '', $value);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the *real* character, maybe by copying, because `“` and `”` **!==** `"`

You can use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$myString = "“iPhone”";
echo str_replace( array( "“", "”" ) , "", $myString );
```

or [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
$myString = "“iPhone”";
echo trim( $myString, "“”" );
```